# Django: Page not found , Raised by:django.views.static.serve

Tags: python, html, django, error-handling

I am trying to display a static image in django. When I select image using django admin portal then it's works fine. it is displaying image. But when I select image from my front-end page, I get:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/destination-2.jpg
Raised by:  django.views.static.server

Here are my codes:
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls')),
]

admin.site.site_header = "Login to our web Portal"
admin.site.site_title = "This is Admin Portal"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to Amnet"

#urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Amnet(models.Model):
    imagee = models.FileField(default='bg_2.jpg')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mainapp.models import Amnet
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        imagee= request.POST.get('imagee')
        am = Amnet(imagee=imagee)
        am.save()
        return render(request,'image-main.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'image-main.html')
```

html page

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <td><input type="file" name="imagee" id="file"></td>
    <td><img src="" id="profile-img-tag" width="200px" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="btn"><br>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enctype="multipart/form-data" to handle file uploads. Add this attribute in the form tag in HTML

Comment: Are you passing images to the html from django views. I couldn't see that in the code.

Comment: Yes, in the html file, it's in line 3 and in the views.py file, its in line 6

Comment: you need to write {{file.url}} in the src in the image